# Table setVisible error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, sapui5

I am trying to hide a table on my HTML page. So I use oTable.setVisible(false). This works fine, i.e my table is hidden but I get the text in place of table as shown below in the picture. Is there any way to not display that or any reason why is it been displayed?
I paste below my code and also the picture for reference.

View.js

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel( "../TEST_ODATA.xsodata",true);
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/sPath");
var oButton1 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                       text : "click",
                       style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Accept,
                       press : function() {

                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = oTable.setVisible(false);
                }});
```

index.html

```
<body class="sapUiBody"> 
<div id="table" style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div> 
</body>
```

Error:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just do it (no need for setting the innerHTML) :

```
press : function() {
     oTable.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Does this also imply for vizCharts ? For example: If I need to replace a Pie chart with a new Pie chart(with new data set on button click), then oPiechart.setVisible(false) works as well?

Comment: I am sorry, I test the same with Pie chart, but the browser throws an error saying ´Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setVisible'´ . I tried something like ´oPiechart.setVisible(false);´. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Sangamesh, you are correct; the VizCharts do not have a setVisible property (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.Pie.html for API reference). You could, however, encapsulate your VizChart in one of the layout containers, for instance a MatrixLayout, which does have a visible property

Comment: However, if you just need a new Pie chart with different data, why not simple set your chart model to this new data? Your pie chart will reflect the data changes in the model instantly

Comment: I would do that when I just need a new chart. BUt I need to change my chart instantly when I filter my table on a ´TextField´ input(ona button press). So I do not have problems doing that. BUt when I place this chart ona  div, the chart is not replacede inside a div rather a new chart appears below. I tried working around with this since two days, but still no success. Any ideas? IN case if you think u need my code for reference. I paste my code here http://jsbin.com/gomovotu/1/edit . Please help :)

Comment: Hi, the problem here is you are creating a new chart on a buttonpress and adding it to the div. Quickest resolution is to clear the barchart div (i.e. `document.getElementById("barchart").innerHTML = '';` ) to get rid of any previous content

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. It's pretty strange for me because for example´"oBarChart2.setModel(oModel2).placeAt("barchart");" ´´document.getElementById("barchart").innerHTML = '';´ . When i run these two lines in order, logically as per my understanding, the ´chart´ is placed in the ´div´ in the first line and immediately the ´div´  content is cleared out in the second line. BUt this doesnt happen and I see the chart still inside the div . What is u r opinion on this?

Comment: huhhu I found the fix. I need to add the position in placeAt like ´oBarChart.placeAt("barchart","only")´. ´only´ removes all the other existing controls in the container and places the current control inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what sapui5 is or where `oTable` comes from, but it looks like your problem is here:

```
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = oTable.setVisible(false);
```

You're setting the HTML inside the #table element to the return value of of the setVisible method.

I imagine you want one (or both) of:

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = '';
oTable.setVisible(false);
```

Recommendation if you want to hide an element would be to style it as such:

```
document.getElementById("table").className = 'hidden';
```

and:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Or if you want to remove an element:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

just set your table to setVisible(false) and invalidate it so that ui5 will rerender it.
this should be enough.

```
oTable.setVisible(false);
oTable.invalidate();
```

and remove your:

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = oTable.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Explain why this would work by [edit]ing the answer.